# ¿cual es la ubicación de directorio que contiene el modulo time de python?

Tags: python

[doc del modulo time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html)

> ubicación de la carpeta contenedora de los módulos pre-instalados de python, con exactitud del modulo time

Comment: Depende por completo de tu instalación. En general, para conocer la ubicación de un módulo puedes mirar su atributo `__file__`, es decir, abres un intérprete python y pones `import module`, y seguidamente `module.__file__` te mostrará la ruta desde la que fue cargado. En cambio para el módulo `time`  esto no sirve porque es un _builtin_, es decir, que el módulo no se carga realmente de ningún sitio sino que forma parte del intérprete. Como tal, no está escrito en python sino en C y en general no puedes verlo salvo si miras el fuente de python.

Comment: Y como puedo mirar el fuente de python ?

Comment: djarte aquí tienes el código fuente: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Modules/timemodule.c

Comment: En github está el [código completo](https://github.com/python/cpython) y el módulo `time` tiene pinta de ser el archivo [timemodule.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/timemodule.c) De todas formas quizás si explicaras para qué lo quieres podríamos encontrar una forma de resolver el problema que no implique leerse ese código tan complejo.

Comment: mil gracias @FJSevilla